# perimeter of "flat" convex polygon

Tags: geometry

I am trying to figure out the perimeter of a "flat" convex polygon, that is, a convex polygon which is collapsed on a segment in some sense, say a triangle with non-null base but null height.

As per definition, the perimeter is supposed to be the length of the curve that meets *sequentially* all the vertices, as a sort of closed curve surrounding the polygon and collapsing on it for some limit. I conclude that the perimeter of a flat polygon is actually twice the length of the segment connecting the two farthest vertices.

e.g. a triangle with vertices (0,0) (1,0) and (2,0) should have a perimeter equal to 4.

But, even zero or just the distance between the two farthest vertices seem reasonable answers, intuitively.

Which is the most honest-to-God answer?

Comment: By Triangle inequality , There is no triangle with $(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)$ vertices. If you collapse the traingle to some limit, the aspect ratio must be same.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi - marco is using a broader meaning for "triangle" than you are, as has been made clear in the post. For this definition, the triangle inequality is $d(a,b) \le d(a,c) + d(b,c)$ - i.e., equality is allowed.

Comment: @marco. You said the perimeter is twice the distance between the farthest endpoints. Then you give an example with farthest endpoints $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$ and claim the perimeter is $0$? How do you get that the distance between $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$ is $0$?  But that aside,  your claim only works for triangles anyway. For flat polygons of four or more sides, the polygon can change directions at places other than the two ends.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair , I wasn't aware what does that mean, thank you for telling me the Triangle inequality. :)

Comment: @PaulSinclair, thank you, I corrected the typo in the post. For this post, you can think the polygon should be convex. A rectangle, for example, would make it. But in general, I can reformulate the question as: "How much is the perimeter of a segment?".

Comment: Consider the *family* of triangles with vertices $(1,0)$, $(-1,0)$, and $(0,h)$. As $h$ varies "continuously", perimeter also varies "continuously". As $h$ *approaches* $0$ —so that the triangle *approaches* "flat"-ness— the perimeter becomes close to $4$. It's appropriate, then, to take the perimeter of the "flat" triangle (when $h=0$) to be exactly $4$, for a continuous family. ... That said, if someone sees what *looks* like a segment, without being told that it's supposed to be a "flat" triangle, it's not-unreasonable for them to interpret "perimeter" as "length of path". Context is key.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi - Since you argued from the triangle inequality, I assumed you knew it. But your statement of no triangle through those points only follows from it being a *strict* inequality. I was pointing out that in the situation described here, it is not strict.

Comment: @marco - if you are going to add conditions to the problem, you need to add them to the post, not mention them only in the comments. However, a simple statement of "convex" doesn't solve the issue, as all flat polygons are convex, regardless of any direction changes. You could restrict it to flat polygons that are the limit of convex *simple* polygons ("simple" meaning that the curve does not intersect itself anywhere). Or you can just require that the polygon can only reverse direction at 2 points.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair Thank you.

Comment: As Blue said, context is key. "Perimeter" is a concept with a consensus meaning (one that almost everyone agrees upon) only for closed boundary curves that never retrace themselves. This doesn't apply to a segment. So if you want to discuss its perimeter, you need to specify what you mean by that. One possible definition for the perimeter of a set $S$ is the limit as $\epsilon \to 0+$ of the greatest lower bound of $\{|\gamma|\mid \gamma$ is a closed curve enclosing $S$ and staying within a distance of $\epsilon$ from $S\}$, where "$|\gamma|$" is the length of $\gamma$. Then $4$ is correct

Comment: thank you all for bearing with the lack of specification of my post. I modified it to specify that I consider convex polygons.